Switch to another View by clicking on an item in LazyVGrid
I want to implement switching to another view by clicking on an item in LazyGrid. How can I do it? I attached my code from LazyGrid.
As far as I understand, it should be done with NavigationLink and onTapGesture, but I'm not sure how exactly to do it. I've tried different tutorials, but I'm not quite sure how I can combine them with my code
struct LazyGridView: View {
        
    let columns = Array(repeating: GridItem(.flexible(minimum: 20)), count: 3)
    var body: some View {
        ScrollView{
            LazyVGrid(columns: columns) {
                ForEach(MockData.colors, id: \.self) {
                    RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 10)
                        .fill($0.gradient)
                        .frame(height: 110)
                        .contextMenu{
                            Button("Edit item"){
                                
                            }
                            Button("Delete item"){
                                
                            }
                        
                        }
                }
                
                
            }
        
            .padding()
        }
    }
}


What view do you want to switch to? Do you want it to appear on top of the navigation stack, or do you want the current view swapped out for it?

Use NavigationStack, NavigationLink, and NavigationPath for data-driven navigation. ADC Documentation
Example:
import SwiftUI

struct DetailView: View {
    @Binding var path: NavigationPath
    let text: String
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Text("\(text)! Oh my!")
            Button {
                path.removeLast()
            } label: {
                Text("Back")
            }
        }
    }
}

struct ContentView: View {
    @State private var path = NavigationPath()
    let columns = Array(repeating: GridItem(.flexible(minimum: 20)), count: 3)
    @State private var animals = ["Lions", "Tigers", "Bears"]
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationStack(path: $path) {
            LazyVGrid(columns: columns) {
                ForEach(animals, id: \.self) { animal in
                    NavigationLink(value: animal) {
                        ZStack {
                            RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 10)
                                .frame(height: 110)
                            Text(animal)
                        }
                    }
                    .buttonStyle(BorderlessButtonStyle())
                }
            }
            .navigationDestination(for: String.self) { textValue in
                DetailView(path: $path, text: textValue)
            }
        }
    }
}

